# SQL Server 2005: Procedure much slower than function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, inline

EDITS:
1. All string literals now have N prepended on them, e.g. `N''` and `N'%'`.  This has had no impact on the timing.
2. I am including links to my execution plans.

Execution plan for function:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxuNJKb4d8Y6elV1OHVUaWVRUU0/edit?usp=sharing

Execution plan for procedure:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxuNJKb4d8Y6cm9SSzFzNWdoVkE/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to re-implement an inline table-valued function as a stored procedure, so that I can dynamically control which columns I compare to while searching (you can see the details below). Unfortunately, the procedure is many (4-5) orders of magnitude slower than the function, which makes it unusable, so I'm coming here for guidance.  As you can see from the procedure guts below, I have already accounted for parameter sniffing (via `WITH RECOMPILE`), and I'm pretty sure I've properly accounted for `ANSI_NULLS`.

My question is, "Why is this stored procedure so much slower than this function, and how do I speed it up to be at least as fast?"

Before it comes up, the reason for the terribly slow double-wildcard searching is that the underlying view cannot be indexed for multiple reasons, such as employing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so I can't employ more clever methods that rely on indexing.

The following block takes approximately 12 seconds.

```
EXEC [db_name].[schema_name].[procedure_name] 
@foo='richard',
@bar='j',
@spam='smith',
@eggs='jr';
```

The following block takes approximately 0 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM [db_name].[schema_name].[function_name]
('richard','j','smith','jr')
```

Guts follow below. The execution plans for the two differ fairly widely, although I am not competent enough at SQL to understand what they say or the impact of their many differences.

I am happy to also share information from the view, if it's relevant; for example, I can tell you that it isn't indexed, and it contains calculated columns using `stuff` (since I do not have access to a proper concatenation aggregate function) and `isnull`, and it employs `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Honestly, I have no idea what COULD be relevant, since both the stored procedure and the function work on the same view with very similar code.

Guts of procedure:

```
USE [db_name]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [schema_name].[procedure_name]
    @foo NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@bar NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@spam NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@eggs NVARCHAR(max) = null
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sqlcmd NVARCHAR(max);
    SET @sqlcmd = N'
        SELECT DISTINCT
        l.this,
        l.that,
        l.other
        FROM [db_name].[schema_name].[view_name] l
        WHERE 1=1';
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(max);
    SET @params = N'    
    @foo NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@bar NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@spam NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@eggs NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ';
    SET @foo = '%' + @foo + '%';
    SET @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + CASE WHEN 
        @foo 
        IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND l.foo LIKE @foo'
        ELSE '' END;
    SET @bar = '%' + @bar + '%';
    SET @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + CASE WHEN 
        @bar 
        IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND l.bar LIKE @bar'
        ELSE '' END;
    SET @spam = '%' + @spam + '%';
    SET @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + CASE WHEN 
        @spam
        IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND l.spam LIKE @spam'
        ELSE '' END;
    SET @eggs = '%' + @eggs + '%';
    SET @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + CASE WHEN 
        @eggs
        IS NOT NULL THEN
        N' AND l.eggs LIKE @eggs'
        ELSE '' END;
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlcmd, @params, @foo, @bar, @spam, @eggs;
END
```

Guts of function:

```
USE [db_name]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [schema_name].[function_name] (
    @foo NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@bar NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@spam NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@eggs NVARCHAR(max) = null
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        l.this,
        l.that,
        l.other
    FROM [db_name].[schema_name].[view_name] l
    WHERE 
        l.foo like ISNULL('%'+@foo+'%', '')
        AND l.bar like ISNULL('%'+@bar+'%', '')
        AND l.spam like ISNULL('%'+@spam+'%', '')
        AND l.eggs like ISNULL('%'+@eggs+'%', '')
);
```

Comment: What do the actual execution plans say? Also every single `NVARCHAR` string you ever define should be defined `N'like this'`, with the `N` prefix, not `'like this'`, without it. Implicit conversion can be a pain in the rear; data corruption is even worse. Try this: `SELECT N'௰', '௰';`

Comment: Also, are you sure the procedure returns the same results as the function, for all permutations of parameter values?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, I know(!), but have you considered implementing a search column such as SearchColumn = [@]foo + N' ' + [@]bar + N' ' + [@]spam + N' ' + [@]Eggs? This allows you to fuzzy search using WHERE SearchColumn LIKE '%[@]InputVariable%'. I'm just taking a punt that this is essentially what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user3056839 that doesn't really work, if the user wants all `foo` that contain `'splunge'` and all `spam` that contain `'rodent'`...

Comment: Won't the first require recompilation of the stored procedure (not the dynamic SQL contained within it) on every execution, while the second will not (as null params will just evaluate to `l.bar like ''`)?  And does the dynamic SQL statement even benefit from the `RECOMPILE` option?  This is a question, as I honestly cannot tell without more details/execution plans.

Comment: I explicitly cast all of my strings that were not (so the '%' strings and the '' strings) as N''; it's clearly better design, even though it had no impact on the speed.  Well spotted.  The function and the procedure do not return the same results for all permutations of inputs; in particular, they differ on NULL inputs.  Does that have a significant impact on the speed here, where none of the inputs are null?  If you like I can modify the function to behave more like the procedure, although it used to do so and was not slower on non-null inputs than it is now.

Comment: It seems clear you guys need the execution plans.  I will go get them.

Comment: Ok, posted the plans.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your function:

```
WHERE
  1 = CASE
    WHEN @foo IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN l.foo LIKE ISNULL('%'+@foo+'%') THEN 1
  END
  AND 1 = CASE
    WHEN @bar IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN l.bar LIKE ISNULL('%'+@bar+'%') THEN 1
  END
  AND 1 = CASE
    WHEN @spam IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN l.foo LIKE ISNULL('%'+@spam+'%') THEN 1
  END
  AND 1 = CASE
    WHEN @eggs IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN l.eggs LIKE ISNULL('%'+eggs+'%') THEN 1
  END
```